# How can I define an array without a fixed size?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, arrays

I want to define an array without a fixed size.

For example: I have an array with numbers (the user will enter these numbers into the array), and I want to divide it into two arrays. But I don't know ahead of time how many numbers the user will enter.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use a [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx).

Fall back to an [ArrayList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.aspx) if [generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172192.aspx) are not available on your target platform (e.g. .NET Framework 1.1 and lower).

Comment: +1: BTW, I would say "or better" to support generic `List<T>` even more :)

Comment: @digEmAll, right, always prefer generics if they're available :)

Comment: ArrayLists are evil unless you need an inhomogeneous list, and are really only there to make the Java crowd happy. List<T> is the way to go.